# Checkbox state isn't changing after click

Tags: react-native, react-native-ui-kitten

I create an app and use react native and ui kitten. The whole thing works with Expo. Now I have implemented a checkbox, but when I tap on the checkbox with the Expo app (iOS), there is no check. The variable is changed, but the state of the checkbox does not change.

```html
<CheckBox
  style={style.checkbox}
    checked={privacyChecked}
    onChange={(checked) => {
      privacyChecked = checked;
    }}
    >
    I accept the Privacy's
</CheckBox>
```

The default value is false. I tap on it and I set the variable to true. But the checkbox isn't changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot update the state with `=` assignment

you need to use `setState` function like

```js
onChange={(checked) => this.setState(checked)}
```

because react will not re-render the component unless it patch the changes and know that it needs to do the re-rendering of component